# Jupyter notebook fails with "Kernel didn't respond"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am running into a strange bug related to the sequential execution of Jupyter notebooks (Python 3 kernels). The main loop runs sequentially the following execution of a set of notebooks through `nbconvert`

```
[...]
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
[...]
class Report:
    [..]

    def execute_notebook(self, timeout=3600):
        [...]
        notebook = nbformat.read(str(self.notebook_path), as_version=4)
        kernel_name = notebook["metadata"]["kernelspec"]["name"]
        ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=timeout, kernel_name=kernel_name)
```

The executions are run on a daily basis. Some days, the loop over the notebooks works smoothly but other it fails when the program tries to execute the second notebook with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/data/ds-metrics/scripts/recurring_reports.py", line 52, in main
    report.execute_notebook()
  File "/home/data/miniconda3/envs/analytics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/report/__init__.py", line 49, in execute_notebook
    ep.preprocess(notebook, dict(metadata=dict(path=self.notebook_folder)))
  File "/home/data/miniconda3/envs/analytics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 359, in preprocess
    with self.setup_preprocessor(nb, resources, km=km):
  File "/home/data/miniconda3/envs/analytics/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/data/miniconda3/envs/analytics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 304, in setup_preprocessor
    self.km, self.kc = self.start_new_kernel(cwd=path)
  File "/home/data/miniconda3/envs/analytics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 258, in start_new_kernel
    kc.wait_for_ready(timeout=self.startup_timeout)
  File "/home/data/miniconda3/envs/analytics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/blocking/client.py", line 124, in wait_for_ready
    raise RuntimeError("Kernel didn't respond in %d seconds" % timeout)
RuntimeError: Kernel didn't respond in 60 seconds
```

After the failures, if I run the loop again, it works. It “looks” really random.

The executions are run on a Debian server from a `conda` virtual environment with Python 3.6.6 and the following list of relevant packages

```
ipykernel                 5.1.0           py36h24bf2e0_1001    conda-forge
ipython                   7.1.1           py36h24bf2e0_1000    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.2.3                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 5.4.0                         1    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
notebook                  5.7.2                 py36_1000    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.6.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
python                    3.6.6                h5001a0f_3    conda-forge
pyzmq                     17.1.2           py36hae99301_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                 py36_1000    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.2.5                hfc679d8_6    conda-forge
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I figured out that I could reduce the problem to the following minimal code

```
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor

ep = ExecutePreprocessor(kernel_name="python3")
km, kc = ep.start_new_kernel()
km.shutdown_kernel()
```

On the cloud server, the script is, sometimes, stuck in (from `strace`)

```
open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY)           = 6
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1
```

Apparently, the server is running out of entropy between the starting of kernels which leads to the long waiting time. A similar issue was indicated [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/342).

I followed the idea and the script is now running smoothly. I guess that, in the original script, instead of starting a new kernel each time, I could reuse the first kernel, preventing the call to the random number generator.